# Pgbadger - report from multiple servers

Tags: postgresql, pgbadger

I've read the documentation for [pg_badger](https://github.com/dalibo/pgbadger), and it says that it can analyze multiple log files, but does that mean that it can analyze logs from multiple servers or just one?

I have to make an sql analysis of five different (postgres) servers (they are all on aws RDS) for slow sql queries, and I was thinking on putting all those log files from those servers on one separate server instance with just pgbadger to analyze them?

That was my thinking, any advice would be valuable.

Comment: I found out the answer! Yes you can! Pgbagder can take logs from multiple postgres servers! Tom